# How set a new one function to know when another function is calling?

Tags: go, aop

I'm working in a Go lang Project. My goal is creating a logging package logging use of some pre-configured functions when they are executed.

I don't want call my logging function in each one, instead I want to define what function calls I want to have logged automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in Go alone. You would have to preprocess your Go source code and instruct the preprocessor to include logging wherever you want. Take a look at how `go test -cover` does such kind of rewriting.